# How to fix a packaged WinUI3 app build, what makes trouble with ProcessorArchitecture?

Tags: azure-devops, winui-3

Today i'm trying to build a .NET 6 WinUI3 App in AzureDevOps. My csproj contains:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0</TargetFramework>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
<Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<PublishProfile>Properties\PublishProfiles\win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
<UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
<EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
<ApplicationIcon>Assets\2764a994e49c43a2932b6d7f465e99eb.ico</ApplicationIcon>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

As "Build Platform" i have defined in Pipelines variable "x64". As error i become:

> [error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.1.2\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Build.Msix.Packaging.targets(1016,5): Error : Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture neutral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a Platform other than AnyCPU.

I'm wondering why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! In Visual Studio, right click on your solution and click properties. For me, a few of the projects didn't have a `Platform` selected. I changed them all to x64 and the build succeeded. Hope this helps.